# Merging branch on remote when it's identical to master

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I've made a branch, commited some changes and pushed it to remote. After that I've merged that branch with master (but only locally) and pushed MASTER to remote. So I'm left with one branch on remote which is identical to master and I can't really merge it with maste. I tried `git merge origin zag902` while being on master, it replies that is already up to date. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Merging a branch won't remove it. You will need to manually delete it either through the web UI, or via the local command;

```
# remove local branch
git branch -d the_local_branch
# remove remote branch
git push origin --delete the_remote_branch
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of this but this is not the issue. I've dealt with the same situation before (also made a branch, commited changes and then merged with master) but the point is, when I look at branches on gitlab.com I can see that branch was merged to master (it has blue tag with 'merged' on it) but there is no such tag on this new branch that I'm talking about.